# Javascript - remove an array item by value

Tags: javascript, arrays

My situation:

```
var id_tag = [1,2,3,78,5,6,7,8,47,34,90];
```

I would like to *`delete where id_tag = 90`* and to return:

```
var id_tag = [1,2,3,78,5,6,7,8,47,34];
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I think the question heading should be "JS - Remove an array element by value in JavaScript"

Comment: @kta It is! You used your mental-mind-powers and the heading reformed itself. Magic.

Comment: @User2 : I do believe in magic but in this case the Author had changed the question title after I wrote my first comment.:)

Comment: See also: [Remove item from array by value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3954438/1048572) and [Remove specific element from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7142890/1048572)

Comment: find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71332975/14229690

Answer (score 227, accepted):

You'll want to use JavaScript's [Array `splice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsplice):

```
var tag_story = [1,3,56,6,8,90],
    id_tag = 90,
    position = tag_story.indexOf(id_tag);

if ( ~position ) tag_story.splice(position, 1);
```

**P.S.** For an explanation of that cool `~` tilde shortcut, see this post:

[**Using a `~` tilde with `indexOf` to check for the existence of an item in an array**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347033/how-to-shorten-my-conditional-statements/18347047#answer-18347047).

---

**Note:** IE < 9 does not support `.indexOf()` on arrays. If you want to make sure your code works in IE, you should use jQuery's `$.inArray()`:

```
var tag_story = [1,3,56,6,8,90],
    id_tag = 90,
    position = $.inArray(id_tag, tag_story);

if ( ~position ) tag_story.splice(position, 1);
```

---

If you want to support IE < 9 but don't already have jQuery on the page, there's no need to use it *just* for `$.inArray`. You can use [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) instead.

Comment: +1 for the safety net.

Comment: I wouldn't inlcude jQuery just for that. A simple indexOf function is available in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: @RobG: Absolutely right. I just assumed that since he tagged his question with [tag:jquery], he already has jQuery on the page

Comment: As noted in the comments to the linked explanation of using the tilde...don't use the tilde.  It's unclear for basically no benefit.

Comment: tilde is not cool. Unmaintainable code is NOT cool!

Answer (score 19):

If you're going to be using this often (and on multiple arrays), extend the Array object to create an unset function.

```
Array.prototype.unset = function(value) {
    if(this.indexOf(value) != -1) { // Make sure the value exists
        this.splice(this.indexOf(value), 1);
    }   
}

tag_story.unset(56)
```

Comment: Not good to extend native JS objects. Plus, OP wants to return the **new array** with the element removed.. it would be nice to return  the new array..

Answer (score 14):

```
tag_story.splice(tag_story.indexOf(id_tag), 1);
```

Comment: Look at the question more carefully, it looks like he wants to remove a value from an array, not an index.

Comment: @Peter Removing an index removes the associated value.

Comment: This code is dangerous! If the value of `id_tag` is not found, it'll delete the last item in the array!! You'll have to first check if `id_tag` was found. See my answer.

Comment: @Matt : when stacks allows me :)) (5 minutes)

Comment: @joseph Silber ... don't know if dangerous but it does what i need!! :) .... maybe my question was not so clear,i'm sorry if it was!

Comment: Just remember that Array.indexOf doesn't exist by default in IE6, IE7 or IE8 so this code won't work in < IE9 without either changing it or installing a shim to add Array.prototype.indexOf

Comment: uhm ... i didn't checked on IE :/ ... thanks for alert!! i need to go .. later i will check better answers and test , then accept right answer ;)

Comment: @Ispuk: This is a very bad habit. You should never use code simply because "it does what I need". You should carefully consider the consequences of *every single* line of code!!!

Comment: @Joseph i'm running and i didn't checked on all browser cause of my 500mb ram pc, it still loading and loading ... i do not have bad habits, but bad pc ://

Comment: I am under the pretense that Ispuk knows that id_tag is in his array. If not, he should make sure the index is not -1 before splicing.

Comment: i just tested your code Eli .. on IE8 it doesn't works unfortunately :( ... it was really good on FF :(

Answer (score 5):

I like to use filter:

```
var id_tag = [1,2,3,78,5,6,7,8,47,34,90];

// delete where id_tag = 90
id_tag = id_tag.filter(function(x) {
    if (x !== 90) {
      return x;
    }
});
```

Comment: If you `return x;` in the callback then `filter` will also *`delete where Boolean(id_tag) = false`*. I think that's unintended.

Comment: Short way: `id_tag = id_tag.filter(x => x !== 90);`

Answer (score 4):

```
function removeValue(arr, value) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] === value) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

This can be called like so:

```
removeValue(tag_story, 90);
```

Comment: this doesn't works as i espected ... the Eli code was exactly what i needed but it doesn't works on IE, check that and check your code , they do not same work :( ...

Comment: this does not return the new array...

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo Thanks, I've edited to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

As a variant

```
delete array[array.indexOf(item)];
```

If you know nothing about `delete` operator, **DON'T use this**.

Comment: Not a good solution, if you use `delete` keyword, you will have an `undefined` element in the array finally.

Comment: This was actually exactly what I needed. Together with array.forEach, I can easily loop through defined indecis.

Comment: Just a heads up that delete will blow up IE8 or lower...

Answer (score 3):

Here are some helper functions I use:

```
Array.contains = function (arr, key) {
    for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
        if (arr[i] === key) return true;
    }
    return false;
};

Array.add = function (arr, key, value) {
    for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
        if (arr[i] === key) return arr[key] = value;
    }
    this.push(key);
};

Array.remove = function (arr, key) {
    for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
        if (arr[i] === key) return arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: OP wants to return the new array. he doesn't want to return the removed value..

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `.indexOf()` and `.splice()`. Something like:

```
tag_story.splice(tag_story.indexOf(90),1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash.js

_.pull(arrayName,valueToBeRemove);

In your case :-
_.pull(id_tag,90);

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer and possibly the link to your source.

Comment: Hope this might help @Andre from [ lodash documnetation](https://lodash.com/docs#pull)

Answer (score 0):

```
var id_tag = [1,2,3,78,5,6,7,8,47,34,90]; 
var delete_where_id_tag = 90
    id_tag =id_tag.filter((x)=> x!=delete_where_id_tag);
```