# How to find the duplicated object in my case?

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to push objects into my array. The problem is some objects are duplicated.

My codes are as following:

```
var obj = {
             'obj1 {
                     'id':'1', 'title':'title 1'
                   },
             'obj2 {
                     'id':'2', 'title':'title 2'
                   },
             'obj3 {
                     'id':'3', 'title':'title 3'
                   }, //duplicated
             'obj3 {
                     'id':'3', 'title':'title 3'
                   },
             'obj4 {
                     'id':'4', 'title':'title 4'
                   }
             // and many more..
          }

var arr= [];

for (i in obj){
   arr.push(obj[i]) 
}
```

I am not sure how to find out the duplicated obj and only push the unique objects into my `arr`.

Can someone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's invalid syntax.  And object properties must be unique, anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350363/add-only-unique-objects-to-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objects are stored in an array (*it's hard to tell via your example*) you could use the following function to get unique objects from that array based on one or more properties of the objects stored:

```
// get unique object members by property name(s)
function unique(arr, props) {
    var results = [],
        seen = [];
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var key = "";
        for (var j=0; j < props.length; j++) {
            key += "" + arr[i][props[j]];
        }
        if (seen.indexOf(key) == -1) {
            seen.push(key);
            results.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return results;
}

var obj = [
    { 'id': 1, 'title': 'title 1' },
    { 'id': 2, 'title': 'title 2' },
    { 'id': 3, 'title': 'title 3' },
    { 'id': 3, 'title': 'title 3' },
    { 'id': 4, 'title': 'title 4' }
];

var results = unique(obj, [ 'id', 'title' ]);
// results => [ obj[0], obj[1], obj[2], obj[4] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dedupe this way if performance isn't an issue.

```
var deduped = {};
for (var i in obj) {
    deduped[JSON.stringify(obj[i])] = obj[i];
}
```