# Add only unique objects to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have object created by function:

```
$scope.checkPosRole = function(possition , posRole , posFunction) {
   var rolePos = {pos: possition, posRole: posRole, posFunction: posFunction}; 
   $scope.rolePossition.push(rolePos);
   };
```

The problem is that I want to in the array was only 1 object with the specified value of `pos`. In the case when the object is added with value `pos` that exists already in the array I want to swap new object with object exist already in array.

I've tried every function call scan the tables with `foreach`, but did not bring me desirable effect. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add only unique objects to an array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350363/add-only-unique-objects-to-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Does the *order* of items matter? If not, simply use an object instead of an array: `rolePositions[rolePos.position] = rolePos`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge duplicate objects in array of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025965/merge-duplicate-objects-in-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```js
var rolePosition = [{ id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];

function addRolePosition(data) {
  var index = -1;
  
  for(var i = 0, i < rolePosition.length; i++) {
    if(rolePosition[i].id === data.id) {
      index = i;
    }
  }
  
  if(index > -1) {
    rolePosition[index] = data;
  } else {
    rolePosition.push(data)
  }
}
```