# How to clear datatable filters?

Tags: datatables

Im using custom filtering for my [datatable](https://datatables.net/) using the method:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push("custom filter function");
```

This function adds a filter to my datatable.

The problem is that when I use ajax to create an other datatable object, this filter persists and is applied to this other table that should have nothing to do with this filter. How do I clear the filter or bind it to the first datatable only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you make a push on $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering, it means it's an array. So when you receive your data, you can remove the filter reference in this array by using :

```
delete  $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering[index or key];
```

this method will set the element to undefined

or by using the splice method in javascript.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.splice(index,1);
```

this method will remove the element from the array.
so

```
var index = $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.indexOf("custom filter function");
 $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.splice(index,1);
```

should resolve your problem
(you can have precision here [Javascript - remove an array item by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142890/js-remove-an-array-element-by-index-in-javascript) as indexOf is not supported by IE<9)

Comment: Or to just remove the last applied filter: `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.pop();`

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to use the 1.10+ version of the datatable in the future, the use of the search plug-in document is shown below:

- [Search plug-in development](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search)

To reset the filter for version 1.10+, simply add any of the following;

- `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search = [];`
- `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();`

after this blocks you can add;

- `table.draw();`

Comment: Erasing of the whole array will break searchPanes - if its been used.  Pop() is a better approach - but only, if you know exactly, that there was only one custom search.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.pop();
```

credit to @DrewT

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned from [@kthorngren](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/185201/#Comment_185201), there is no build in way of tracking, if or how much custom searches are active.
If you are sure, that there is only one custom search is active a
`$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.pop();`
will work - there is big **BUT:**

`$.fn.dataTable.ext.search` is an array which contains the search settings for custom search and for searchPanes.
An erasing of this array with `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search = [];` or two pop()'s, allthough there is only one custom search is active --> will brake searchPanes.

e.g. if you have three panes active, this would mean:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search[0] -> SearchPane Col1
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search[1] -> SearchPane Col2
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search[2] -> SearchPane Col3
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search[3] -> Custom Search -> safe to delete
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search[4] -> Custom Search -> safe to delete
```

Following code does the job in my case:

```js
let lenOfSearchPanes = dt.settings()[0]._searchPanes.c.columns.length;
let lenOfSearchArr = $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.length;
let diff = lenOfSearchArr - lenOfSearchPanes
if (diff > 0) {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search = $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.slice(0, -diff);
}
```