# Why does .splice always delete the last element?

Tags: javascript

In the javascript, there are two arrays:`tags[]` and `tags_java[]`. I use `.splice` to delete certain items, which of the same index in the two arrays. The `tags[]` works fine, but `tags_java` doesn't, it seems always delete the last item.
Here is the **code** and **[the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/1017/)**.

```
var tag = $(this).text();
var index = $.inArray(tag, tags);
    tags.splice(index,1);
    tags_java.splice(index,1);
```

Comment: Can you provide/check the value of index, tags array and tags_java array just before u perform slice on either of them..?

Comment: Your tag is never in the array - that appended `&times;` is showing up as part of the span's text, so `$.inArray()` always returns -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah, both don't work, because you're not actually finding the correct index of your tag.

Why not? Because `$(this).text()` includes the delete mark you added, `×` - e.g. "Morning×". Since that's not in your `tags` array, `index` will be -1. `tags.splice(-1, 1);` will remove 1 item from the end of the array.

In general, it's never a good idea to use presentation text (i.e. the text of your tag element) as data (e.g. using that text as a lookup value in an array). It's very likely that it'll be broken when something changes in the presentation - like here. So a suggestion would be to store the data (what you need to look up the tags) *as* data - e.g. using the jQuery-provided `data()` API - even if it seems redundant.

Here's a quick example - just adding/replacing two lines, which I've marked with comments starting with "JT": [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJHM8/4/)

Now, instead of looking up by `$(this).text()`, we're looking up by the data value "tagValue" stored with `$(this).data()` - that way, the lookup value is still bound to the element, but we're not relying on presentation text.

Comment: Thanks @JimmiTh. But how can I fix it? How can I trim the "&times" from the text?

Comment: You could use `var tag = $(this).text(); tag = tag.substr(0, tag.length - 1);` to remove the `&times;`, but as mentioned in the second paragraph, that's very error prone. Adding an example to the answer of what I mean by storing the data *as* data.

Comment: But for now the lookup value is stored with the content "'<span class="label label-afternoon">Afternoon</span>','<span class="label label-morning">Morning</span>' because if I store them as numbers like'1,2..', I don't know how to retrieve the information in another page. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean - the code in the JSFiddle (updated) works *exactly* like your original code - except it uses `data()` on the tag element, rather than `text()`.

Comment: Thanks @JimmiTh, that works great. I will have a good look on the .data. It's a great idea. I meant after you store these data values, like '300,301,302' in this case, how can I display them in another page with specific content and colors. Is this clearer?

Comment: That's really a rather big question - which also depends on your server-side code etc. I'd suggest creating a new question for it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the `tag` is not in the `tags` array, `$.inArray` will return `-1`, which would then cause the last item to be deleted.

[You have to make sure that the item is actually in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142890/js-remove-an-array-element-by-index-in-javascript/7142909#7142909).