# Removing return carriage from an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

I have array as shown below:

```
 ["↵", "Oh", "yeah,", "did", "we", "mention", "it’s", "free?↵"]
```

Is there a way I can remove that ↵ from the string and from the array?
I tried

```
str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

This didn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142890/remove-an-array-element-by-value-in-javascript)

Comment: are you actually after `↵` or CR and LF? Also, do you want to remove the whole array element (containing that character) or just remove that character from the strings inside the array?

Comment: this is just one of the many arrays. Im not looking to remove that specific array alone. I did a string split to return an array. Its a string that hold that character,

Comment: Already figured you were doing that. Solution: then split the string on `/\s+/` and bob's your uncle `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply split your string on `/\s+/`, then you don't need to perform this action anymore.

```
var str='\nOh yeah, did we mention it’s free?\n';
var arr=str.split(/\s+/);
```

Note: you *might* want to trim `\s+` from the beginning and end of the string fist. (Older) Browsers that do not support `trim()` can use:

```
arr=str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(/\s+/);
```

---

Strictly answering your question how to remove 'carriage returns' from strings in an array:

```
// you have:
var str= '\nOh yeah, did we mention it’s free?\n';
var arr= str.split(' ');

// no function needed, a simple loop will suffice:
for(var L=arr.length; L--; arr[L]=arr[L].replace(/[\n\r]/g, ''));
```

Note that (as can already be seen in your example as array-item 0) you might end up with some empty strings (not undefined) in your array.

Comment: In that case I would need to split on space character and /\s+/

Comment: What do you mean by that? `/\s+/` includes space.

Comment: No problem. Extra note: you *might* want to trim `\s+` from the beginning and end of the string fist. Browsers that do not support `trim()` can use: `arr=str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(/\s+/);`

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up your array from empty strings using `String.prototype.trim` combined with `Array.prototype.filter` to remove falsy values. For example:

```js
var arr = ["\n", "", "Oh", "yeah,", "did", "we", "mention", "it’s", "free?\n"]

// check array before
alert(JSON.stringify(arr));

arr = arr.map(function(el) {
    return el.trim();
}).filter(Boolean);

// after cleaning up
alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function removeReturn(ary){
  var b = [], a = [];
  for(var i=0,l=ary.length; i<l; i++){
    var s = ary[i].split('');
    for(var n=0,c=s.length; n<c; n++){
      if(s[n] === '\u021B5')s[n] = '';
    }
    b.push(s.join(''));
  }
  for(var i=0,l=b.length; i<l; i++){
    var x = b[i];
    if(x !== '')a.push(x);
  }
  return a;
}
```