# javascript split string selected text remove

Tags: javascript, web, split, visual-web-developer

How do I delete a fragmented of text from within a string with javascript

Example String:

```
var start = "World,Book,Pencil,Door";
```

Now, when I select any of the selected values: `"World"`, I want the result to be `"Book,Pencil,Door"`.

```
// result = "Book,Pencil,Door";
```

Comment: Are you asking how to take an array of strings and return an array with 1 fewer element in it? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Please share the code you already have and show what's not working. We'll gladly help you solve this. Possibly answers related to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142890/javascript-remove-an-array-element-by-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to remove a value from a comma separated string, try this ...

```
var removeValue = function(list, value, separator) {
  separator = separator || ",";
  var values = list.split(separator);
  for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    if(values[i]===value) {
      values.splice(i, 1);
      return values.join(separator);
    }
  }
  return list;
}
```

If the value you're looking for is found, it's removed, and a new comma delimited list returned. If it is not found, the old list is returned.

Another version ... using indexOf

```
var removeValue = function(list, value, separator) {
  separator = separator || ",";
  var values = list.split(separator);
  var index = values.indexOf(value);
  if(index >= 0) {
    values.splice(index, 1);
    return values.join(separator);
  } else {
    return list;
  }
}
```

Basically, with either function you send the list (`"World,Book,Pencil,Door"`) as a string, the value to remove (`"World"`) as another string and what the separator is (`","` for comma ... however, comma is also the default so can be left off).  If the value to remove does not exist in the list, it will return the list.  If it is in the list, it will be removed.

**Example 1**:

```
var final = removeValue("World,Book,Pencil,Door", "World");
// final = "Book,Pencil,Door"
```

**Example 2**:

```
var final = removeValue("World,Book,Pencil,Door", "House");
// final = "World,Book,Pencil,Door"
```

**Example 3**:

```
var final = removeValue("World|Book|Pencil|Door", "World", "|");
// final = "Book,Pencil,Door"
```

**UPDATE**:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/96awa2ht/

Comment: Is it going to be like?


var removeValue = function(list, value, separator) {
var final = removeValue("World,Book,Pencil,Door", "World");
  separator = separator || ",";
  var values = list.split(separator);
  var index = values.indexOf(value);
  if(index >= 0) {
    values.splice(index, 1);
    return values.join(separator);
  } else {
    return list;
  }
}

Comment: No, removeValue is the function ... the first line can also be written as `function removeValue(list, value, separator) {` ...

Comment: `var final = removeValue("World,Book,Pencil,Door", "World");` is executed somewhere else in your code to generate your new list with **World** removed.