# Remove an item from an array by value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I have an array of items like:

```
var items = [id: "animal", type: "cat", cute: "yes"]
```

And I'm trying to remove any items that match the ID given. In this case; `animal`

I'm stuck! I can get it to work easily by having a more simpler array but this is not what I need... I also need to remove the item by value as I don't want the hassle of referring to items by their index.

Is there a jQuery method I could use where I don't need to iterate through the items array, rather specify a selector?

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zafrX/

Comment: Your syntax is invalid.  Do you have an array or an object?  You have mixed the syntax.

Comment: If you look in the javascript console (firebug, in my case), it raised that error, 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'
You should create an object Item, and you will be able to access easily attributes of the Item

Comment: object `var items = { id: "animal", type: "cat", cute: "yes" }`, array `var items = ["animal", "cat", "yes" ]`

Comment: My bad! I will remove it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not sure how much of a hassle it is to refer to array items by index.  The standard way to remove array items is with the [splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    if (items[i] === "animal") { 
        items.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
```

And of course you can generalize this into a helper function so you don't have to duplicate this everywhere.

---

**EDIT**

I just noticed this incorrect syntax:

```
var items = [id: "animal", type: "cat", cute: "yes"]
```

Did you want something like this:

```
 var items = [ {id: "animal",  type: "cat", cute: "yes"}, {id: "mouse",  type: "rodent", cute: "no"}];
```

That would change the removal code to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    if (items[i].id && items[i].id === "animal") { 
        items.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: items.splice(items.indexOf("animals"), 1)

Answer (score 11):

No need for jQuery or any third party lib for this, now we can use the new ES5 filter :

```
let myArray = [{ id : 'a1', name : 'Rabbit'}, { id : 'a2', name : 'Cat'}];
myArray = myArray.filter(i => i.id !== 'a1');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can either use `splice` or run a delete yourself. Here's an example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i ++) {
    if (items[i] == "animal") { 
        items.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a simple way!

```
myItems.splice(myItems.indexOf(myItems.find(row => row.id == id)), 1);
```

Demo below:

```js
// define function
function delete_by_id(id) {

  var myItems = [{
    id: 1,
    type: "cat",
    cute: "yes"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    type: "rat",
    cute: "yes"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    type: "mouse",
    cute: "yes"
  }];

  // before
  console.log(myItems);

  myItems.splice(myItems.indexOf(myItems.find(item => item.id == id)), 1);

  // after 
  console.log(myItems);

}

// call function
delete_by_id(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do it like this (make sure that you have the right syntax...you cannot have array with properties, but object inside `{}` and then you can iterate by keys and delete unwanted key):

```
var items = {id: "animal", type: "cat", cute: "yes"}
var removeItem = "animal"; // or with the ID matching animal...

for(var p in items){
    if(items[p] === removeItem)
        delete items[p]
}
```

And to answer you question, you cannot apply jquery selectors to javascript objects. The best you can do to avoid `for` loop is to use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) (which is a loop written in a more "functional" way).

Comment: I think this might be the right answer.  I missed OP's incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 2):

By using object notation : http://jsfiddle.net/jrm2k6/zafrX/2/

```
var animal1 = {id: "animal", type: "cat", cute: "yes"}
var car2 = {id: "car", type: "pick-up", cute: "no"}
var animal3 = {id: "animal", type: "dog", cute: "yes"}
var removeItem = "animal"; // or with the ID matching animal...

var array_items = []
array_items.push(animal1);
array_items.push(car2);
array_items.push(animal3);

for(var i=0;i<array_items.length;i++){
    if(array_items[i].id == removeItem){
        array_items.splice(i,1);
    }
}

//alert(array_items.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so many ideas but still not what I wanted xD

This will remove ALL entries of the given value and return the removed value:

```
function removeOfArray(val, arr){
    var idx;
    var ret;
    while ((idx = arr.indexOf(val)) > -1){
        arr.splice(idx, 1);
        ret = val;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Also I found other solutions here:
[Remove item from array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/remove-item-from-array-by-value/25183401#25183401)

Answer (score 0):

```
-parray : list of array of object
-pstring :value to remove from the array
-ptag :using which tag we
```

```js
function removeFromArr (parray,ptag,pstring){
 var b =[];
var count = 0;
for (var i =0;i<parray.length;i++){
 if(pstring != parray[i][ptag]){
 b[count] = parray[i];
 count++;
 }
}
 return b;
}

var lobj = [ {
 "SCHEME_CODE": "MIP65",
 "YEARS": "1",
 "CURRENCY": "GBP",
 "MAX_AMT": 200000,
 "MIN_AMT": 1000,
 "AER_IR": "1.80",
 "FREQUENCY": "Monthly",
 "CUST_TYPE": "RETAIL",
 "GROSS_IR": "1.79"
 },
 {
 "SCHEME_CODE": "MIP65",
 "YEARS": "2",
 "CURRENCY": "GBP",
 "MAX_AMT": 200000,
 "MIN_AMT": 1000,
 "AER_IR": "1.98",
 "FREQUENCY": "Monthly",
 "CUST_TYPE": "RETAIL",
 "GROSS_IR": "1.96"
 },
 {
 "SCHEME_CODE": "MIP65",
 "YEARS": "3",
 "CURRENCY": "GBP",
 "MAX_AMT": 200000,
 "MIN_AMT": 1000,
 "AER_IR": "2.05",
 "FREQUENCY": "Monthly",
 "CUST_TYPE": "RETAIL",
 "GROSS_IR": "2.03"
 },
 {
 "SCHEME_CODE": "MIP65",
 "YEARS": "5",
 "CURRENCY": "GBP",
 "MAX_AMT": 200000,
 "MIN_AMT": 1000,
 "AER_IR": "2.26",
 "FREQUENCY": "Monthly",
 "CUST_TYPE": "RETAIL",
 "GROSS_IR": "2.24"
 },
 {
 "SCHEME_CODE": "QIP65",
 "YEARS": "1",
 "CURRENCY": "GBP",
 "MAX_AMT": 200000,
 "MIN_AMT": 1000,
 "AER_IR": "1.80",
 "FREQUENCY": "Quarterly",
 "CUST_TYPE": "RETAIL",
 "GROSS_IR": "1.79"
 },
 {
 "SCHEME_CODE": "QIP65",
 "YEARS": "2",
 "CURRENCY": "GBP",
 "MAX_AMT": 200000,
 "MIN_AMT": 1000,
 "AER_IR": "1.98",
 "FREQUENCY": "Quarterly",
 "CUST_TYPE": "RETAIL",
 "GROSS_IR": "1.97"
 },
]

function myFunction(){
 var final = removeFromArr(lobj,"SCHEME_CODE","MIP65");
 console.log(final);
}
```

```html
<html>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</html>
```

are going to remove from the objects

```
function removeFromArr(parray, pstring, ptag) {
        var farr = [];
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < pa.length; i++) {
            if (pstring != pa[i][ptag]) {
                farr[count] = pa[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        return farr;
    }
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post.

Answer (score 0):

**ES6 Solution**

```
persons.splice(persons.findIndex((pm) => pm.id === personToDelete.id), 1);
```