# Remove from array without using index number

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove item from array by value | JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/remove-item-from-array-by-value-javascript)

How can I remove *dog* from the below array using Javascript. I do not want to use index
if I can avoid it but rather the word dog instead.

```
["cat","dog","snake"]
```

Comment: What, "do it for me"? No. Go do some research.

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/remove-item-from-array-by-value-javascript

Comment: @Andrew: Good find... voted to close.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3954451/465546

Answer (score 17):

Given an array:

```
var arr = ["cat", "dog", "snake"];
```

Find its index using the `indexOf` function:

```
var idx = arr.indexOf("dog");
```

Remove the element from the array by splicing it:

```
if (idx != -1) arr.splice(idx, 1);
```

The resulting array will be `["cat", "snake"]`.

Note that if you did `delete arr[idx];` instead of splicing it, `arr` would be `["cat", undefined, "snake"]`, which might not be what you want.

[Source](http://wolfram.kriesing.de/blog/index.php/2008/javascript-remove-element-from-array)