# Binding an unique value from a table to ng-model of a check box

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angular-ngmodel

I have a table(which is populated with the data that is received from back end using ng-repeat.)Each of the rows have a check box and if the check box is selected(multiple) i want to send a request to the server to delete the rows.To do this i want to bind my check box to an unique field in my table but am unable to get the right syntax.
i tried the below options that i read in SO but nothing seems to work.

```
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="demo.Custid" >//this replaced the value in the table with true or false.

  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.checkboxes[demo.Custid]" >//this gave me values in the below  format {"12500":true,"125001":false}
```

Is there anyway i can get the value of the customer id(in this case)directly bound to the ng-model uniquely?I want to get these values and send a request to the server to delete the data from the table for the corresponding customer.

```
 .controller('Controller1',function($scope,$rootScope,$routeParams){
 $scope.name = 'Controller1';
 $scope.params = $routeParams;
 $scope.formData = {
            checkboxes: {}

                   };
 $scope.demos = [
                 { 'Account':'abc.com',
                   'Custid': 125000,
                    },
                   {'Account':'abc.com',
                   'Custid': 125001, },
                     { 'Account':'abc.com',
                   'Custid': 125002,}
                 ]


         })
```

I am new to angular js and any help/pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng-click.

You already have an ng-repeat looping over demo. Seeing $scope.demos and demo.Custid, I assume you just did

ng-repeat="demo in demos".

Now just pass that demo.Custid to a function defined on the scope using 
    ng-click="myfunction(demo.Custid)"

I adapted your code a little to make it easy for myself but this should be pretty obvious:

**Edit :** I just realized I was using an angular 1.01 template in jsfiddle to create this code, I'll leave it but here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RobbyD/5frc79d4) to a working example in angularjs 1.5.5

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="Controller1">
  <input type="submit" ng-click="sendToBackend()">
  {{name}}
  <table>
    <thead><tr><td>Select</td><td>Customer</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="demo in demos">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-click="addToList(demo.Custid)"></td>
        <td>{{demo.Custid}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody> 
  </table>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="check in checkboxes">{{check}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**myapp.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function Controller1($scope) {
   $scope.name = 'Controller1';
   $scope.checkboxes = [];
   $scope.demos = [{Account: 'abc.com',Custid: 125000,}, 
                   {Account: 'abc.com',Custid: 125001,}, 
                   {Account: 'abc.com',Custid: 125002,}];
   $scope.addToList = function(id) {
      $scope.checkboxes.push(id);
   };
   $scope.sendToBackend = function() {
      alert("sending " + $scope.checkboxes.length + " items to backend");
   };

};
```

From here on you should be able to do everything that you want with it. If you have more specific questions, shoot!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robby.I tried your method .it's perfect except that  if the user clicks on the check box and then uncheck it , the value will still be added to the list that is to be deleted .

Comment: One way you could do that is by passing the event so that in your html this becomes ng-click="addToList($event, demo.Custid") and in your function definition $scope.addToList = function($event, id). Then check if $event.target.checked is true and add it to the array, if false search for it in the array and remove it. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792927/javascript-array-search-and-remove-string). Of course the function should probably be renamed to updateList instead. Also, if this answered your questions please mark my reply as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank so much Robby.I just tried it out today and It works perfectly :)