# How to find multiple string items in an array and delete the string that matches the search and return the count of the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, splice

```
var stringsToSearch = ["cat", "dog", "rat"];
fromThisArray = ["rabbit", "snake", "cow", "cat", "dog"];
```

If `stringToSearch` is found in fromThisArray, It should delete those strings and return the count of the array.

Similar question were asked in this forum but they are finding single string but my requirement was to search multiple string and delete those string.

Comment: post your attempts

Comment: There are lot of questions of similar type on SO. Just do some research work

Comment: Please format your code and add more description to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript array search and remove string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792927/javascript-array-search-and-remove-string)

Comment: No Efforts posted duplicate. question available on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `filter` and `indexOf`

```js
var stringsToSearch = ["cat", "dog", "rat"];

var fromThisArray = ["rabbit", "snake", "cow", "cat", "dog"];

var filteredArray = fromThisArray.filter(function(item){
  return stringsToSearch.indexOf(item) < 0;
});

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: Thank you every one for your time on this and all answers were close to my requirements.

Comment: @skellysanthu Glad, this helped you. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
var stringsToSearch = ["cat", "dog", "rat"];
var fromThisArray = ["rabbit", "snake", "cow", "cat", "dog"];

for(var i=0; i<stringsToSearch.length; i++){
    var idx = fromThisArray.indexOf(stringsToSearch[i]);
    if(idx > -1){
        fromThisArray.splice(idx, 1);
    }   
}

console.log(fromThisArray, fromThisArray.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function uniqueCount(arr, stringsToSearch ){

  for(var i = 0; i < stringsToSearch.length ; i++){
    while(arr.indexOf(stringsToSearch[i])> -1){
       arr.splice(i,1);//remove
    }
  }
  return arr.length;
}

var stringsToSearch = ["cat", "dog", "rat"];
var fromThisArray = ["rabbit", "snake", "cow", "cat", "dog"];

//call the function 
console.log(uniqueCount(fromThisArray , stringsToSearch ));
```