# remove string element from javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

can some one tell me how can i remove string element from an array 
i have google this and all i get is removing by index number

my example :

```
 var myarray = ["xyz" , "abc" , "def"] ; 
 var removeMe = "abc" ; 

  myarray.remove(removeMe) ; 
  consle.log(myarray) ;
```

this is what i get from the console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object xyz,abc,def has no method 'remove'
```

​
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mTuys/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/3955096/711129:

```
Array.prototype.remove= function(){
    var what, a= arguments, L= a.length, ax;
    while(L && this.length){
        what= a[--L];
        while((ax= this.indexOf(what))!= -1){
            this.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return this;
}
var ary = ['three', 'seven', 'eleven'];

ary.remove('seven')
```

or, making it a global function:

```
function removeA(arr){
var what, a= arguments, L= a.length, ax;
while(L> 1 && arr.length){
    what= a[--L];
    while((ax= arr.indexOf(what))!= -1){
        arr.splice(ax, 1);
    }
}
return arr;
}
var ary= ['three','seven','eleven'];
removeA(ary,'seven')
```

---

You have to make a function yourself. You can either loop over the array and remove the element from there, or have this function do it for you. Either way, it is not a standard JS feature.

Answer (score 20):

Since you're using jQuery

`myarray.splice($.inArray("abc", myarray), 1);`

**EDIT**
If the item isn't in the array, this 'one-liner' will likely throw an error. Something a little better

```
var index = $.inArray("abc", myarray);
if (index>=0) myarray.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery for this.

Comment: Some browsers don't support `indexOf`. Jquery's `inArray` will abstract the funcationality from the browser.

Comment: +1 for using `>=0` http://jsperf.com/not-vs-gt-vs-ge/4 (and for correct answer ofc)

Comment: far easier if you're using jQuery already, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Try like below,

```
myarray.splice(myarray.indexOf(removeMe),1);
```

You can add this below script ([from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)) for browsers that doesn't support indexOf

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {  
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {  
        "use strict";  
        if (this == null) {  
            throw new TypeError();  
        }  
        var t = Object(this);  
        var len = t.length >>> 0;  
        if (len === 0) {  
            return -1;  
        }  
        var n = 0;  
        if (arguments.length > 0) {  
            n = Number(arguments[1]);  
            if (n != n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN  
                n = 0;  
            } else if (n != 0 && n != Infinity && n != -Infinity) {  
                n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));  
            }  
        }  
        if (n >= len) {  
            return -1;  
        }  
        var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);  
        for (; k < len; k++) {  
            if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {  
                return k;  
            }  
        }  
        return -1;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: One comment, some browsers don't support `indexOf`

Comment: Also, if `indexOf` doesn't find the element, you are gonna splice with index `-1` which still removes an element

Answer (score 0):

more simple solution

```js
var myarray = ["xyz" , "abc" , "def"]; 
var removeMe = "abc";

var theNewArray = myarray.filter(s => s !== removeMe);

console.log(theNewArray); // will return ["xyz" , "def"]
```