# JavaScript - remove from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var arr = [ 4, "Pete", "test", 8, "John", "", "test" ];
```

How can  i remove from this array values **test** and empty string? How is the best method for this?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/remove-item-from-array-by-value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var arr = [ 4, "Pete", "test", 8, "John", "", "test" ]; 
var l = arr.length;

while( l-- ) {
    if( arr[l] === "test" || arr[l] === "" ) {
        arr.splice(l, 1);
    }
}

//> arr
//[4, "Pete", 8, "John"]
```

Comment: `arr.splice( arr.indexOf('test'), 1 );`

Comment: @jAndy not really, there are multiple items to be removed. And using indexOf multiple times here would be cringeworthy because of the `n²`-ess

Comment: oh yea you're right. didn't realize there are multiple values. My solution was flawed anyhow because of `-1` false positives on no-match

Answer (score 2):

Alternative: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/filter)

```
var arr = [ 4, "Pete", "test", 8, "John", "", "test" ]
           .filter(function(v){return String(v).length && v !== 'test';});
//=> arr = [4, "Pete", 8, "John"];
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter` works non-destructive, you need to assign the value back to `arr`. Beside that, why not just calling `return v !== 'test';` ?

Answer (score 1):

check it may help you if you want to remove single Item

http://jsfiddle.net/HWKQY/

Answer (score 0):

if you know the index of your item in array you can easily use splice like

arr.splice(index,howmany)

howmany=The number of items to be removed

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp