# What is the best way to add/remove an element from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete an array key when it contains a string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076200/delete-an-array-key-when-it-contains-a-string-in-javascript)

by using jquery, underscore or native javaScript I would like to delete or add element to an array.

here is my code;

```
var a = ['4', '5'];
var remove = false/true; 

if(!remove) {
     a.push('6'); // it works
} else {
     a.remove(5); // I have no idea how to perform this in a very dry way
}
```

Comment: there was same questions [JavaScript Array Delete Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)

Comment: Read this http://codeforbrowser.com/blog/javascript-arrays/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you combine NULL and dystroy's answer you can get Niko's answer(ish) in pure js:

```
a.splice(a.indexOf('5'),1);
```

Or if you wanted to remove multiple '5's

```
var p;
while( (p = a.indexOf('5')) != -1 ){
    a.splice(p, 1);
}
```

A neater method, that is rather unoptimal, only modern-browser supported (and also creates a new array) - but is still valid and more flexible is:

```
a = a.filter(function(v){
  return v != '5';
});
```

Comment: This only works expected if `'5'` is only represented once.

Comment: Yep, as I said... (ish) - it all depends on what Lorraine Bernard actually requires.

Comment: +1 it's a pretty neet while loop.

Answer (score 2):

**Native JavaScript:**

```
a.splice(1, 1); // ['5']
a // ['4']
```

You can replace the value with new elements:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.splice(1, 1, -1, -2) // [2]
a // [1, -1, -2, 3]
```

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: See my answer for complete answer, you're only doing half the work as OP doesn't know the index.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
delete a[1];
```

or

```
delete a[a.indexOf('5')];
```

or

```
a.splice(a.indexOf('5'), 1);
```

if you don't want to have a `undefined` in your array.

For compatibility with IE8, you may want to [add a common patch for indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Doesn't removes the item but sets it to `undefined`

Comment: @NULL it does actually remove the element but it does not reindex the array (move the elements after the removed element to one position ealier)

Comment: @NULL I perfectly know it, see duplicate from yesterday. It depends on OP's goal, that's why I proposed the two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Underscore:

```
a = _.without(a, '5');
```

See http://underscorejs.org/#without

Comment: This doesn't remove the element from the array : this builds a new array and leaves the original array untouched.

Comment: that will remove all values of '5' not just one

Comment: By the question it looks like the OP is requesting the removal of the value rather than the offset however - they do not specify if they wish to remove all values however.

Comment: @Pebbl how do you interpret "The best way to add/remove **an** element from an array?" to meen anything than removing an(/one) element?

Comment: @RuneFS because I'm reading what they put below the title. The JS they submitted doesn't actually make sense - it could be read in two ways, hence not being 100% sure of what they require. Plus the question has since been edited and (I admit I haven't looked at the revision) but quite often the title is the first thing to be "rearranged".

Answer (score 0):

Use `splice()` method:

```
if(typeof Array.prototype.remove === "undefined") {
    Array.prototype.remove = function(e) {
        this.splice(this.indexOf(e), 1);
    }
}

var a = ['4', '5'];
a.remove('5');
alert(a);​
```

Prints:

```
4
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B8YCx/1/)

Comment: I know this is a john resig kind of thing but there is no reason the extend the prototype chain...

Comment: yep.. especially without using `Object.defineProperty` to stop it being enumerable otherwise you'll break a lot of `for(i)` in older code.

Comment: @NULL And why not? It's more convenient to use `a.remove(e)` whereas `a.splice(a.indexOf(e), 1)`, right?

Comment: It's a longer talk you can find many articles on google. eg: http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/