# How doI reduce an array to a specific amount in javascript/jquery/undescore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array like:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Now I want to just have the first 3 items. How would I remove the last two *dynamically* so that I could also have a 20 letter array, but reduce that down to the first 3 as well.

Comment: Please refer to similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/remove-item-from-array-by-value

Comment: What if you construct another array with the first three elements and than exclude that original array, if you don't need it anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
a.slice(0, 3); // ["a", "b", "c"]

var b = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"];
b.slice(0, 3); // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)?

```
var firstThree = myArray.slice(0, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) function seems to be what you're after. You could do something like:

```
myArray.splice(3);
```

This will remove all items after the third one.

Answer (score 2):

To extract the first three values, use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var my_arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var new_arr = my_arr.slice(0, 3); // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

To remove the last values, use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
var removed = my_arr.splice(3, my_arr.length-3); // second parameter not required
// my_arr == ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In underscore.js we can use the **first** function

**_.first(array, [n])** Alias: head

*Returns the first element of an array. Passing n will return the first n elements of the array.*

```
_.first(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],3);
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```