# How do you return an array in Javascript minus a single item without copying the array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove item from array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/remove-item-from-array-by-value)

I am maintaining string lists like

```
var keyString = [];

keyString.push("anotherString");
keyString.push("yetAnotherString");
keyString.push("oneLastString");
```

I want to be able to return all results from `keyString` less a value I already know about.

For example, if I have *anotherString*, then I want to return everything in the array that isn't *anotherString*.

Obviously this can be done a few ways easily, but I have some restrictions.

**I don't want the solution to use any loops, and I don't want to use excessive amounts of memory, and I don't want to modify the original array**.

This may be impossible, but I thought I would throw it out there and see if anything exists.

Comment: You don't want to copy the Array, you don't want to modify the original, but you want to end up with an modified version of the original. How exactly would that work?

Comment: Here is some magic powder to make it go away.

Comment: This isn't remotely a duplicate to Removing something from an array.

Comment: It was an exact duplicate until you changed the question to make it an impossible request.

Comment: Who on earth gives something like this a +1. I'd really love to hear what's goes through your head.

Comment: @user1689607: Likely OP's *other* account to compensate down votes...

Comment: @user1500053: Your question was perfect duplicate until you added *...don't want to modify the original array*. I do have a question: Are you limited to using an array or are you flexible to using associative array (objects)?

Comment: yeah, I dont get off on SO status, only have the one account.  No it is not limited to using an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possibilities considering your example code, but inside a function (or `return` wouldn't make sense). The examples assume you're fine with modifying the original array, since you don't want to copy.

**1. Using [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to remove the first element**

```
function something() {
    someObject["keyString"] = [];
    someObject["keyString"].push("anotherString");
    someObject["keyString"].push("yetAnotherString");
    someObject["keyString"].push("oneLastString");
    someObject["keyString"].shift(); 
    return someObject;
}
```

**2. Using [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to remove the last element**

```
function something() {
    someObject["keyString"] = [];
    someObject["keyString"].push("yetAnotherString");
    someObject["keyString"].push("oneLastString");
    someObject["keyString"].push("anotherString");
    someObject["keyString"].pop(); 
    return someObject;
}
```

**3. Using [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the middle element**

```
function something() {
    someObject["keyString"] = [];
    someObject["keyString"].push("yetAnotherString");
    someObject["keyString"].push("anotherString");
    someObject["keyString"].push("oneLastString");
    someObject["keyString"].splice(1,1); 
    return someObject;
}
```

Comment: Just for the record, `.splice` and `.unshift` are pretty likely to be linear-time, though probably implemented with native code.  (That is, they're probably "loops" internally, if that matters to the OP.)

Comment: These won't work since I can't garauntee that its the first or last item in the array and splice modifies the original array. ( I will edit to include that as a restriction)

Comment: @user1500053 So you don't want to modify the original array, and don't want to copy either? I guess there's no way, then.

Comment: @Pointy sorry for ask, what does OP mean. I have seen this for several times today, haven't figured out yet

Comment: I was thinking maybe there is some way that you could return an array that are references to the objects in the original array.  But I guess, in retrospect the array is just references anyway to objects so filter will probably work.

Comment: @user1500053 If an array value is an object, a copy of that array will reference the same object. But if the value is a primitive, you'll get a copy of the value.

Comment: @xiaoyi it's an acronym for "Original Post" - on Stackoverflow, it's a way of referring to the original question that was asked.

Comment: @xiaoyi: or **Original Poster**... Depending on the context being used. It's very handy when you can't tell from the user name whether OP is male or female. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), but this will return a new array as well:

```
var newArray = keyString.filter( function( el ) {
  return el !== 'anotherString';
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

Not bulletproof but it works:

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
a.splice( a.indexOf("c"), 1 );

console.log(a); // ["a", "b", "d"];
```