# Javascript: Remove an element from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
var items = [{ id: 1, text: "test1" }, { id: 2, text: "test2" }, { id: 3, text: "test3"}];
```

I have the following object:

```
var itemToRemove = { id: 2, text: "test2" };
```

I want to check by id if `itemToRemove` exists in the `items` array.

And remove it:

```
  // pseudo code
  items.remove(itemToRemove);
```

I went through javascript array methods but found nothing that will do the job. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove item from array by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/how-to-remove-item-from-array-by-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse the array by using a plain loop and then remove the matching item by using [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
for( var i=0; i<items.length; i++ ) {
  if( items[i].id == itemToRemove.id ) {
    items.splice( i, 1 );  // remove the item
    break; // finish the loop, as we already found the item
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
items.filter(function (item) {
    return item.id !== 2 || item.text !== "text2";
});
```

It's generally not a good idea to mutate the original array or else I would recommend Sirko's answer. The `filter` method produces a whole new array. It doesn't mutate the original array.

Comment: +1, but this won't work in crappy (i.e., IE < 9) browsers. You'd have to use some kind of a shim to [add the filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to the Array object.

Comment: @Robusto `if (![].filter) Array.prototype.filter = function (callback, that) { var index = 0, length = this.length, list = []; while (index < length) { var item = this[index]; if (callback.call(that, item, index++, this)) list.push(item); } return list; };`