# How can I remove a index in the array on the javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, indexof

My javascript code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clubs = [ 
        {id: 1, name : 'chelsea'},
        {id: 2, name : 'city'},
        {id: 3, name : 'liverpool'}
    ];
    if(clubs.indexOf(2) != -1)
        clubs.splice(2, 1)
    console.log(clubs)
</script>
```

For example, I want to delete the index with id = 2

I try like that, but it does not work. The index with id = 2 is not deleted

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Your array consists of objects but you're looking for the index of the _value_ `2`. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property) for solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Remove an element from an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958429/javascript-remove-an-element-from-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var clubs = [ 
        {id: 1, name : 'chelsea'},
        {id: 2, name : 'city'},
        {id: 3, name : 'liverpool'}
    ];

clubs = clubs.filter(function(item){
   return item.id !== 2;
});

console.log(clubs);
```

Comment: @downvoter - Reason please? What's the point of down-vote if the reason is not specified?

Comment: Why not point to one of the many duplicate questions instead of repeating a solution here? Plenty of solutions for this on SO.

Comment: @H77 - The highest voted answer has a different approach, so wrote my approach as an answer. Fair I guess.

Comment: Probably better to add your solution there and mark this one as a duplicate. That way the answers wouldn't be scattered.

Comment: @nikhilagw I think this is the only decent answer suggested. I didn't downvote it. But I think H77 is right.

Comment: @H77 - The general tendency is to follow the top answer. My answer there can be an option but to put it over here makes it more valuable. I believe there is difference in opinion on how to handle the situation.

Comment: It's the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property). Like I said.. plenty of duplicates. No reason to add more.

Comment: @H77 - Now the point is taken. However, you could see that there are still plenty of duplicates and you cannot do much about it. What really matters is how fast you get/search the solution or the proposed solution. It took some time of yours to get to the above link, however, 18 minutes back you had a link to a different approach. For me it was important to know the reason of down-vote, and I honor your reason but I have my own opinion about it and would like to stick to it. Thank you for all the clarification.

Comment: @H77 - Apologies for bringing this up again, however, in addition to above, it would be better to close the issue and mark it as duplicate rather than down-voting a correct possible solution.

Comment: @H77 - You made the right choice. :) Then may I request the down-voter to list his/her reason?

Comment: @downvoter - Reason please? What's the point of down-vote if the reason is not specified?

Comment: @nikhilagw Great. It works. Thanks a lot. I accept your answer and I voted for it. It's help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to solve your problem, check this :

```js
var clubs = [
  { id: 1, name: 'chelsea' },
  { id: 2, name: 'city' },
  { id: 3, name: 'liverpool' }
];

for (var i = 0; i < clubs.length; i++) {
  if (clubs[i].id == 2) {
    clubs.splice(i, 1);
    break;
  }
}

console.log(clubs);
```

Comment: Both way is fine . Yes using strictly typed is better .  It cant be the reason to downvote. lol.Answer edited

Comment: Oh boy. Its javascript. . Its ok. Answer edited. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

The element is not getting deleted because of your if statement, you are checking  if `2` is present or not in array, but there is nothing like 2 in array as it is an array of objects. So the condition always remains false.