# Remove an item from javascript array based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array in javascript. I need to remove an item from it. I have to iterate over the array and check whether there is a value called 'mastercheck'. If the value is there in array, I have to remove it and get the remaining items. How to do?

Typically my array consists of value like mastercheck,60154,60155....

Comment: Loop thru your array values,compare it and then remove..

Comment: Please do some basic research before asking and state a specific problem you face. Do not ask others to do your work.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/remove-item-from-array-by-value

Comment: Post what you have tried to come up with.

Comment: sorry. I am a comp science student of diploma. So don't know much about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First use the indexOf method to determine the index of the item with the needed value. Then you can use the splice method to remove the item at found index.

Something like that:

```
var array = ['mastercheck', '60154', '60155'];
var index = array.indexOf('mastercheck'); // get the index
array.splice(index, 1); // remove the item
```

Comment: mine bit to slow :(.yours +1 ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = ['mastercheck',60154,60155];

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i] === 'mastercheck'){
        arr.splice(i,1);
    } 
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdfYp/)

```
var arr = ['mastercheck', '60154', '60155'];
var index = arr.indexOf('mastercheck');
arr.splice(index, 1);
```