# How can I remove items from an array in javascript ? I want something like a pull to do the opposite of push

Tags: javascript

I would like my application to have an area of the screen that tracks activity.

I created the following:

```
$scope.activity = [];
```

What I am thinking of is that when something starts I will push onto this array like this:

```
$scope.activity.push("Loading content 1");
$scope.activity.push("Loading content 2");
$scope.activity.push("Loading content 3");
$scope.activity.push("Loading content 4");
```

I can then have an area of my screen that shows what is happening with an ng-repeat that shows everything in the array:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in activity">
    {{ row }}
<div>
```

My problem is I am not sure how to remove the items from the array once the activities have completed. Can someone give me a suggestion as to how I could do this. What I really need is some kind of pull function where I can specify the name of what I pushed and have it removed. Something like:

```
 $scope.activity.pull("Loading content 4");
```

Also I need another function such as:

```
 $scope.activity.update("Loading content 4", status);
```

I'm looking for a solution that does not use jQuery, or underscore. Myusers are IE9 and above.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/remove-item-from-array-by-value

Comment: See if this helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var activityArray = [];
activityArray.push("Loading content 1");
activityArray.push("Loading content 2");
activityArray.push("Loading content 3");
activityArray.push("Loading content 4");

//find the item we want to delete
var index = activityArray.indexOf('Loading content 4');// returns 3
activityArray.splice(index,1)//remove the item at index 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

> Changes the content of an array, adding new elements while removing old elements.

Comment: I'm sorry I just added something else to the question. I hope I can use your suggestion also for updating.

Comment: This is what you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Methods.

Answer (score 1):

[`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) and [`.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) are often used along with `.push()`.