# How to remove set of item values of array from another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var myFind_collections =[3,6,10,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,244,245,246,247,248,248,249,250];
var pgRangeCollection = [234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,244,245,246,247,248,248,249,250];

for(v=0;v<=pgRangeCollection.length;v++){
    var pgMatch = pgRangeCollection[v];
    clear_pg_range(pgMatch);
    }

function clear_pg_range(pgMatch){
        //for(d=0;d<=myFind_collections.length-1;d++){
        for(d=0;d<=myFind_collections.length-1;d++){
            var docFound = parseInt(myFind_collections[d]);
            if(pgMatch===docFound){
                    myFind_collections.splice(myFind_collections[d],1);
                    alert(docFound + " was removed");
                }
            }
    }

alert(myFind_collections.length);
```

in above code i want to remove every item in myFind_collections which equals to pgRangeCollection

i want the output as (3,6,10)
but i am getting the output as (248,249,250)

i dont know where i mistaking can anybody suggest solution for this,

Thanks in advance

Comment: See if this helps https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L518-L523

Comment: There is smth like you are asking on SO already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/remove-item-from-array-by-value

Comment: You might find it handy to use a set and use the difference method on the set: https://github.com/jfriend00/Javascript-Set/blob/master/set.js.  Arrays aren't very efficient at doing lookups like you're doing here.  That's what sets (implemented in JS with an object and properties on the object) are for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Array.filter`

```
var myFind_collections =[3,6,10,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,244,245,246,247,248,248,249,250];
var pgRangeCollection = [234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,244,245,246,247,248,248,249,250];
var filtered = myFind_collections.filter(
                  function(a){return pgRangeCollection.indexOf(a) < 0}
               ); // => [ 3, 6, 10 ]
```

[**See also**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (`filter`) and [**also**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (`indexOf`)

Comment: myFind_collections.filter is not a function

Comment: Read the articles from the links in my answer, especially the *Polyfill* section

Comment: Are you testing on a version of IE < 9 ? Because it is not implemented in this so called browser versions

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be using the .filter method as already proposed by KooiInc but since IE is a requirement I would use the difference method of Lodash or Underscore:

```
_.difference(myFind_collections, pgRangeCollection) // [3,6,10]
```

Just include it via cdn:
http://cdnjs.com/libraries/lodash.js/

or if you already have jQuery:

```
 $(myFind_collections).not(pgRangeCollection).get() // [3,6,10]
```