# Delete elements within an array that include a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array with strings and I need every element that include a certain string to be deleted.

```
var arr = ["abc", "123", "dfg", "bbb"];

var string = "b"
```

After deleting any elements that include the **string**, the array should look like this:

```
["123", "dfg"];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove item from array by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/remove-item-from-array-by-value)

Answer (score 4):

Simple to do with `Array.prototype.filter`:

```js
var arr = ["abc", "123", "dfg", "bbb"];
var string = "b";

alert(arr.filter(function (i) { return i.indexOf(string) < 0 }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate through the array and collect all the items which do not contain the string.
You can use `indexOf` function to find an occurence of one string into an other.

```js
    var arr = ["abc", "123", "dfg", "bbb"];
    var string = "b";

    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i].indexOf(string) === -1) 
        {
            result.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Please, notice, that I have added a `document.body.innerHTML = result;` line in order to display results. Do not forget to remove it before using in your code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method also, Check following snippet.

```js
var arr = ["abc", "123", "dfg", "bbb"];
var string = "b";

arr.splice(1,1);
document.getElementById("ans").value = arr[1];
```

```html
<input id='ans' type='text'>
```