# how to remove the specific value in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i like to remove specific data in input text value using jquery but showing wrong data

```
<input id="value1" type="hidden" name="value1" value="352880,350906,341563">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
var value = $('#value1').val();
$('#value1').removeData( "352880" );
var value = $('#value1').val();
alert(value);
</script>
```

Comment: what is `removeData`? where is your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-a-string-breaking-at-a-particular-character & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/remove-item-from-array-by-value

Answer (score 3):

try below solution:

```html
<input id="value1" type="hidden" name="value1" value="352880,350906,341563">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
var value = $('#value1').val();
var valArr = value.split(',');
var removeItem = '352880';
valArr = $.grep(valArr, function(value) {
    return value != removeItem;
});
var value = valArr.join(',');
alert(value);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = $('#value1').val();

var values = value.split(",")

alert(values[0] + "this will be the required value to be deleted");
```

delete in loop

```
values = $.each(values,function(v){

 return v!= values[0];

})

values.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution - https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/kffw2a5h/

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<input id="value1" type="hidden" name="value1" value="352880,350906,341563">
<script type="text/javascript">
var value = $('#value1').val();
var values = value.split(","); 
var i = values.indexOf("352880");
if(i != -1) {
    values.splice(i, 1);
}
$('#value1').val(values.join());
alert(values);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this to be accurate even if the value is first in between or last and get rid of extra comma values.

```
var value = $('#value1').val();
var values =value.split(',');

var removeItem = '352880';

values = jQuery.grep(values, function(value) {
  return value != removeItem;
});

value = values.join(',');
alert(value);
```