# Angularjs way to remove item from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

How can I make the `playerinit` remove the seat used from `emptyseats`?
lets say `seatid` is 1, then it will remove `seat: 1` from `emptyseats`?

```
   vm.emptyseats = [
      {seat: 1},
      {seat: 2},
      {seat: 3},
      {seat: 4},
      {seat: 5},
      {seat: 6},
      {seat: 7},
      {seat: 8},
      {seat: 9},
    ];


    vm.playerinit = function(x) {
      console.log("init user data");
      var seatid = x.position;

      // vm.emptyseats remove where seat: seatid

    };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove item from array by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/remove-item-from-array-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using native `Array#filter` function:

```
vm.playerinit = function(x) {
      console.log("init user data");
      var seatid = x.position;

      // vm.emptyseats remove where seat: seatid
      //Using ES6 arrow function syntax
      vm.emptyseats = vm.emptyseats.filter( (empty_seat) => empty_seat.seat !== seatid);
      //Or regular syntax
      vm.emptyseats = vm.emptyseats.filter( function(empty_seat) {     return empty_seat.seat !== seatid});

    };
```

Comment: It should be noted that [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#AutoCompatibilityTable) is IE9+. Still a good answer, though.

Comment: Thanks @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia ! . Will accept it as soon as i can.

Comment: @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia what do i do if i want to add into array with seatid 3?

Comment: for adding into array you need using `Array#push` method. Example: `vm.emptyseat.push({seat: 3})`

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to find the index of the array you want to remove. Then, use [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
var seatid = x.position;
angular.forEach(vm.emptyseats, function(emptyseat, i) {
    if(emptyseat.seat !== seatid) return;
    vm.emptyseats.splice(i, 1);
});
```

Comment: As far as I know, `forEach` is not supported on IE8 too.

Comment: Duh, thanks @Mistalis. I guess I'm used to having a shiv for that one. I've updated to use Angular's `forEach()`.

Answer (score 1):

A native JS approach, IE 9+

```
vm.emptyseats = vm.emptyseats.filter(function(a) { return a.seat != seatid; });
```

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it with a simple `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < emptyseats.length; i++) {
    if(vm.emptyseats[i].seat == seatid) vm.emptyseats.splice(i, 1);
}
```

---

With your full code:

```
vm.playerinit = function(x) {
  console.log("init user data");
  var seatid = x.position;

  // vm.emptyseats remove where seat: seatid
  for(var i = 0; i < emptyseats.length; i++) {
      if(vm.emptyseats[i].seat == seatid) {
          vm.emptyseats.splice(i, 1);
          console.log(seatid + " removed!");
      }
  }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using `.splice()` to do this. 
`vm.emptyseats.splice(0,1);`