# Javascript remove null from object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having afunction that is merging two arrays like this:

```
var sorting = data.genre.map((i) => data_info.find((o) => o.id === i));
```

The problem in this function is if it couldn't find `genre` in `data_info` it adds `null` to the object arra and therefore my function fails.
So the question is: **How could I remove in above single line all values that are null?**

I get this output from thr line above:

```
[{"id":1,"category":"Action"},{"id":2,"category":"Adventure"},null]
```

And need to get this:

```
[{"id":1,"category":"Action"},{"id":2,"category":"Adventure"}]
```

I tried to add `&& data_info(o) !== null` to the line above but I get `null` in the object array anyway.

Comment: Add a `filter` to the output of `map`. `data.genre.map((i) => data_info.find((o) => o.id === i)).filter((i) => return i != null );`

Comment: The map function applies the operation on each item of the array and returns an array with exactly the same number of elements as in the input array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove item from array by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/how-to-remove-item-from-array-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `.map` to `.filter`

```
var sorting = data.genre.filter((i) => data_info.find((o) => o.id === i) ? true : false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` method by passing a callback provided function.

```
var sorting = data.genre.map((i) => data_info.find((o) => o.id === i)).filter(function(item){
    return item!=null;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `filter` the result of your `map` function to remove `null`.

```
var sorting = data.genre.map((i) => data_info.find((o) => o.id === i)).filter(item => {
   return item !== null;
});
```

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.