# remove particular value from array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image]

I have these type of array in javascript.Now i want to remove the value from array which name is "PropertyType[]".How to do it.Here i upload the picture of array.Here in Newremoveurl array i get the array value.

```
var Newremoveurl = [];
        var Parant_name = 'PropertyType';
        $.each(Removeurl_array, function( key, value){
            var decoded_key = decodeURI(value);
            if ($.inArray(Parant_name, Newremoveurl)!='-1') {

            } 
            Newremoveurl[key]=decoded_key;
        });
```

Comment: Post your array code

Comment: i upload thearray  image

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, why not taking advantage of `grep()` or, if you're not targeting older browsers, use `Array#filter`?

Comment: Yes and this is a problem

Comment: any solution for these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove item from array by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/how-to-remove-item-from-array-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

you can filter your array to remove these with standard javascript
for an exact match - you can remove  like this

```
const filteredResults = myArray.filter(item => item === "PropertyType[]")
```

or for values which contain a string

```
const filteredResults = myArray.filter(item => item.indexOf("PropertyType[]") ===-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=myArr.length; i--;) {
     if (myArr[i].indexOf("PropertyType")>=0) break;
}
```

Value of i will be -1 if PropertyType* does not exist, or else it would be the index of the element.

Then cut the element from the array with

```
if (index > -1) {
    myArr.splice(index, 1);
}
```

You can run this solution till the value of i becomes -1, then your array would hopefully be free of the element you do not require.