# Mongoose : How to remove item from array by value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Is there a method to remove an item from an array with Mongoose?
I have an array inside object like this:

> "students": [
>               "5ad72254452996029415e49f",
>               "5adaeb388acfc414d428820b"
>           ]

And I'd like to remove one of them by identified value.
This is my code :

```
Company.findById(id_company, function(err, company) {
  var students = company.students; //students array
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...
});
```

Students is an array, and I'd like to update and remove one of array element inside it by ID.

Comment: Do you want to persist your changes into the database or you just want to alter the array in memory?

Comment: simple `.splice` would work

Comment: Please check this stack question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/how-to-remove-item-from-array-by-value

Comment: If I'm using .splice, it remove all of array element, what I want is just remove specific element by ID.

Comment: you'd probably be doing it in wrong way. How are you doing it ? and  as @TsvetanGanev mentioned, do you want to persist it in your db ?

Comment: students.splice(id_student);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you must do a *$pull* on your array attribute:

```
const deleteStudentStatement = {
    $pull: {students: studentId}
};
```

Then do an update, for example:

```
return Company.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: companyId }, 
                                deleteStudentStatement, 
                                { new: true })
                     .then((company) => {
                           },
                           (err) => {
                           }
                     );
```