# Removing Item from API / Array in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying my best to remove an item from my array.

I have attempted to filter it as following:

```
removeContact(contact) {
this.setState({
   contacts: this.state.contacts.filter((_, i) => i !== contact)
 }); }
```

But that doesnt seem to do the trick.

My contact is listed in an unordered list like this:

```
<ul className="list-group">
        {this.state.contacts.map(((contact, index) =>
          <li className="list-group-item" key={`${contact.contact}${index}`}>
            {contact.name} | {contact.phone} | {contact.countryId} <button  onClick={this.removeContact}>Delete</button>
          </li>
          ))
        }

      </ul>
```

But by clicking remove it just throws an error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

The list to render the contacts from the api works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove item from array by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/how-to-remove-item-from-array-by-value)

Comment: need more information. What is a type of contact? and how does it not work?

Comment: Tried to add a little more information

Comment: Use an arrow function, change `removeContact() {}` to `removeContact = () => {}`

Comment: You are setting this.state.data - but trying to map this.state.contacts.  Did you mean to setState on the 'contacts' key?  Additionally - @Dan is on the right track.  You either need to bind 'this' in constructor or use an arrow function.

Comment: That fixed the error @Dan but it doesnt seem to remove the contact

Comment: Yes @LukeT Fixed it along with Dans answer - it just doesnt remove the contact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
removeContact = (index) => () => {
  this.setState({
    contacts: this.state.contacts.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
  }); 
}
```

I guess you want this. You have to inject index to use inside event listener.

```
<button onClick={this.removeContact(index)}>
```