# Find an item in array and get whats left

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the other item out of an array. I have an array called fruit and a variable called apples. I want to go through the array and find any other fruit apart from the one I already have.

Thanks in advance for any help

```
var fruit =  [
        "apples",
        "pears"
    ];

var alreadyHave = "apples";


for( var i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++){
    if (! fruit[i] === alreadyHave) {
        fruit.splice(i, 1); 
    }
}

console.log(fruit);
```

I would like to set the remaining fruit as another variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove item from array by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/how-to-remove-item-from-array-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter method for this:

```
const leftFruits = fruit.filter(f => f !== alreadyHave);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `filter()` function

```js
var fruit =  [
        "apples",
        "pears"
    ];

var alreadyHave = "apples";
console.log(fruit.filter(x => x !== alreadyHave))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#filter` to achieve this:

```js
var alreadyHave = "apples";

var fruit = [
  "apples",
  "pears",
  "banana",
  "orange"
];

/* Create a new variable/array with all fruit items except for apples */
var remainingFruit = fruit.filter(item => alreadyHave !== item);

console.log(remainingFruit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript filter() method for it

```
var fruit =  [
    "apples",
    "pears"
];

var alreadyHave = "apples";

var filteredFruit = fruit.filter(item => item !== alreadyHave);
```

Answer (score 0):

let fruit =  [
    "apples",
    "pears"
];

let alreadyHave = "apples";

let fruitsExceptAlreadyHave = fruit.filter(element => element !== alreadyHave);